What legally happens when an owner is removed from a company for bad behavior
A while back there was some drama surrounding one of the Try Guys, where the offending member cheated on his wife with an employee. He was kicked out of the company.
I’m just wondering how that legally works. If he was just a normal employee, I would assume they could just fire him and be done. But because he was one of the original group, I’m assuming he had at least some stake in the company. So would they have had to buy him out despite him causing a lot of harm to the brand and opening the company up to legal trouble if the subordinate decided to sue?
I’m guessing a concrete answer wouldn’t be possible without seeing actual contracts, so a general answer would also be sufficient

It's entirely possible that he was removed as an employee (which management can do, as they could do to any employee) without losing his ownership stake.  He could vote his shares in favor of management who would reinstate him, but if he has a minority stake, he could lose that vote.

Cheating on someone is not a crime, nor is sleeping with an employee. So why did the company care at all?

@PMF It turns out that several companies have rules other than "don't do crimes."

At one company we were told in a company meeting "don't do anything that looks like insider trading". Even if it wasn't actually insider training, but if someone watching the company could get the impression. And I suspect the problem wasn't "cheat on his wife" but "with a company employee".

Yes, the main issue was that it was with a subordinate. Every company I have ever had to do HR training for has language that specifically prohibits that kind of behavior because of the potential for abuse and subsequent legal trouble.

@PMF Public personalities, like actors, musicians, spokespeople, have morals clauses in their employment contracts because they being hired in a large part for their reputation.

@PMF The company cares because the principals have to go to work every day full time and interact productively with each other. Something like cheating on your wife with a company employee may irrevocably damage interpersonal relationships and any sense of trust in the core management group of the company.

@ohwilleke That's one side to look at, but on the other hand, I'm pretty sure that there where cases where this behavior has led to a heir to take over the company... In times before Tinder & Co, the workplace was a primary place to find one's significant other (with or without cheating).

There isn't a general answer to this question.
The grounds, if any, for removing a business owner from management and/or ownership of a closely held business are usually specified in the governing documents agreed to by the parties in that particular entity. These terms vary greatly and are not infrequently the subject of active negotiations when an entity is formed.

I don't know how to corroborate it, but someone on Reddit wrote:

in this LLC, they were setup were all 4 Try Guys were owner-managers, and the way they setup the bylaws is that the 3 could agree to kick the 4th out. So that's what they did. This LLC seems to be more of a partnership (eg accountants, doctors, engineers, architects, than a traditional C-corp.)

